# generate random number in a range in assembly

Tags: assembly, random, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to genarate a random number between -27 and +33 in assembly.

There is a procedure called `Randomize` that generates a random number between  0 and n where n is the upper bound.

How to shift the lower bound to be -27 not 0?

This is the code:

```
title test
INCLUDE irvine32.inc


.data
msg byte "Genrating 50 number",0
.code
main PROC
mov edx,offset byte
call WriteString
call crlf
mov ecx,50
L1:
mov eax,+33
call RandomRange
call writeDec



exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: I suggest you try to solve this in a higher-level language first (e.g. C), and then translate to assembler.

Comment: Try generating a random number between 0 and 60, then subtract 27 from it.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use RandomRange to generate integers from 0 to (33+27-1), then subtract 27 from the generated number.
The code below is to fill an array with n randomized integers and display the array.
The randomized range is [-27,33]

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
j equ 27
k equ 33
n =10

.data
arrayd sdword n dup(?)

.code
main proc
call randomize ;activate the seed
mov ecx,n
mov esi,0
L1:           ;the trick is the 3 instruction lines shown below
   mov eax,k+j
   call randomrange
   sub eax, j
   mov arrayd[esi*4],eax
   inc esi
   loop L1

   mov ecx,n
   mov esi,0
L2:
   mov eax,arrayd[esi*4]
   call writeInt
   mov al,20h
   call writechar
    inc esi
    loop L2
exit
main endp
end main
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code:

```
include Irvine32.inc  
.data

.code
main proc
mov ebx, -27
mov eax, 33
mov ecx, 50

L1:
pushad          ; save all 32bit registers
call BetterRandomRange
call writeint
call crlf
popad           ; restore all 32bit registers
loop L1
main endp

BetterRandomRange proc
neg ebx
add eax, ebx
call randomrange
sub eax, ebx
ret
BetterRandomRange endp


end main
```

[see more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnPJQ.jpg)

Comment: No comments to explain what it's doing, and unnecessary slow instructions like `pushad` / `popad` and `loop` .  This just does the same thing 50 times because of the pushad/popad.  Also, execution falls through the end of `main` into `BetterRandomRange` before eventually returning.